# Wikipedia API / Date Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, wikipedia-api

[image]I would like to use Wikipedia API to get event results on a date, not just the list of the event, but the first 3 articles.

Like when I searched March 3rd, the 1st event on the list is like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/473.

Is there a way to do that?

```
var wikiURL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php";
wikiURL += '?' + $.param({
    'action' : 'query',
    'list' : 'search',
    'srsearch' : 'keyword',
    'format' : 'json',
    'srprop': 'titlesnippet',
});
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, can you clarify? So you want this result? (The first 3 events by place from wikipedia) https://gyazo.com/abe73e49369689e95f78b49eb814150b

Comment: Good morning Xatenev, date March 3 is searched, in the event list, the 1st one if Gundobad, I have attached the screenshot of the page that I would like to generate on date api call.  Thank you for replying to my post.

Comment: I am not familiar with the wikipedia api but maybe you can parse https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=473&prop=sections to get a list of all the sections, find the one with `Events` and then call https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=473&prop=wikitext&section=1&format=json (replace section=1 with the parsed section ID from before.) There is probably a better way, that is just my first approach skimming through docs. Read through the wikipedia api docs to find better/other ways.

Comment: Thank you Xatenev, it is still no coming out the result that I wanted, but thank you for  your help.